# Question about the radius of the smallest enclosing disk containing $k$ points of a point-set

Tags: geometry

I am reading a book where in the middle of a lemma's proof the author 
assumes something without explaining the step. I am struggling to show why that is true.

Consider a finite point set $P$ with $n$ points in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. The author does not assume the points to be in general position.

Let $r_{opt}(P,k)$ be the radius of the smallest closed disk which contains $k$ points of $P$, where $k\leq n$.

Let depth$(P,\alpha)=$ maximum number of points from $P$ that can lie inside a disk of radius $\alpha$.

Then the author in the course of the proof assumes that depth$(P,r_{opt}(P,k))=k$

I am unable to show this. Clearly, depth$(P,r_{opt}(P,k)) \geq k$, otherwise 
a disk of $r_{opt}(P,k)$ will never be able to contain $k$ points. But why should it be *equal*  $k$?

Also suppose $P$ consists of the 4 corners of a square. Then isn't $r_{opt}(P,3) = 4$ ? Any 3-size subset of the $P$ cannot have a smaller enclosing circle 
than the square's circumcircle, and this circumcircle necessarily contains 4 points.

Comment: Is there an assumption that the $n$ points are in "general position" or something like that?

Comment: No.  I have made the edit about that to update my quesiton.

Comment: Then it looks like you've got a valid counterexample.